# Is it impossible to have more than one alias?

Tags: apache, httpd.conf, vhosts

I'm configuring `httpd` on Windows 10, and everything is okay - Except the fact that I can't configure more than one alias to the same `VirtualHost`.

My `extra/httpd-vhosts.conf` file (Variables are configured in `httpd.conf`):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # Define Server Defaults
    ServerAdmin "${SERVER_ADMIN}"
    ServerName "${SERVER_NAME}"
    ServerAlias "www.${SERVER_NAME}"

    # Define public_html Directory
    DocumentRoot "${PUBLIC_HTML}"

    # Define Log Paths
    ErrorLog "${ROOTDIR}/logs/${SERVER_NAME}-error.log"
    CustomLog "${ROOTDIR}/logs/${SERVER_NAME}-access.log" common

    # Create phpMyAdmin alias
    Alias "/phpmyadmin" "${PMA}"
    <Directory "${PMA}">
        Require local
    </Directory>

    # Create an alias for old `public_html` directories
    Alias "/archive" "${ROOTDIR}/archive/"
    <Directory "${ROOTDIR}/archive/">
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

When I check `httpd -t` I receive `Syntax OK`, and I can access http://localhost/phpmyadmin/,
But I can't access http://localhost/archive/.

Screenshot:
[image: phpMyAdmin]

phpMyAdmin is ok, but:

[image: localhost/archive]

`/archive` not.

Why?

Thank you for your help, and Please excuse my bad english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem Solved: Yes Indeed! All I needed was:

```
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Multiviews
```

Inside `<Directory ...></Directory>`.

Code:

```
<Directory "${ROOTDIR}/archive">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Multiviews
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```